# Extending "specific" defaultdict(str,...)?

Tags: python, string, defaultdict, extending

You can extend defaultdict() like this :

```
class Ext(defaultdict):
```

how do I extend instead the string-default variant :

```
defaultdict(str, .....)
```

I expect it to be something along the lines :

```
class Ext(defaultdict):

   def __init__(self, str_arg, **args):
         super(Ext,self).__init__(str, **args)
```

str_arg is so I can skip the first argument and always instantiate it like defaultdict(str,{}) .

Comment: That is not a distinct type. It doesn't make sense to extend it.  You can create a subclass which defaults to having a string factory

Comment: What do you mean by extending? Do you want something like `defaultdict(str, 'some_default_string')` and all values are default to `some_default_string`?

Comment: You have it already, mostly, but what is `str_arg` supposed to be used for?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
class Ext(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ext, self).__init__(str)
```

In other words, you don't want to ignore the first argument to `__init__()`; you want to supply an additional argument to the superclass `__init__()` method invocation.

(If you want to accept more arguments to your subclass `__init__` of course do put those back in.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea, but if you insist on developing a subclass of `defaultdict` that only functions if the `default_factory` is `str`, you can simply state that like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict


class MyDict(defaultdict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        assert self.default_factory is str


# in action:

try:
    x = MyDict(str)
    print('Fine')
except AssertionError:
    print('Unexpected')

try:
    x = MyDict(int)
    print('Should not work')
except AssertionError:
    print('Expected issue')
```

Comment: Requiring you to always pass in `str` explicitly anyway seems like a poor design choice. You can pass in an argument but it always has to be the same static value? You'd want to encapsulate that.

Comment: Agreed @triplee - answering the question because I can think of some remote use cases where it's the only choice you have, but fully agree on it being a total anti-pattern.